# how to do a counter timer which when end will show a div which will hold for a time and restart again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I was doing a countdown timer when the timer end it will show a div and it will hold for a time and restart again

For example i set it for 7 days when the time reach deadline it will hold the div for 7 days and recount for 7 days again.

i can implement a simple timer when the time end it will show a div but i no sure how to let it recount again  and show it up again and again.I no sure how to make the timer to be static when refresh the timer will still continue to run wont recount again

here is my jsfillder -

```js
var time = 5;

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test() {
  time -= 1;
  $('#test').html(time);

  if (time == 0) {
    $('#test').remove();
    $('#a').show();

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="border:1px solid black;width:100px">test

</div>

<div id="a" style="display:none;">
  testing
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var time = 5,        // keep this unchanged!
    counter = time;  // we'll change this reference instead

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test() {
  counter -= 1;
  $('#test').html(counter);
  if (counter === 0) {
     counter = time;  // see?
     // Do something here.... 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="border:1px solid black;width:100px">test</div>
```

Comment: how to make it as static? when refresh browers the timer wont be recount again?

Comment: @Chew "recount again" is not something I understand. You mean... you want to store the current user visited time? The time should be relative or absolute? You could use `localStorage` and compare dates using `new Date()`

Comment: For example the timer is 5 minute when the time left 3 minute refresh the browser the time rwill still be left 3 minute wont be start with 5 minute again

Comment: @Chew than do as I said in my comment.